# Laravel scheduler nonoverlapping method

Tags: laravel, laravel-scheduler

I want to run a nonoverlapping job but the command is just never called

Here is my code

```
$schedule->command('start_listeners')->withoutOverlapping();
```

I also tried this

```
$schedule->command('start_listeners')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();
```

When i remove the withoutOverlapping method it works perfectly fine

Comment: Do you have the cronjob set up? [Running The Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler)

Comment: When i remove the withoutOverlapping method it works perfectly fine